# How to write Serial instance for this function?

Tags: haskell, smallcheck

Suppose, I have types like

```
data D = A | B String | C String
data TestIt m = TestIt {
   x :: m Int
 , y :: Int -> m D
}
```

and I am writing SmallCheck test, so I need `Serial` instance on `TestIt`:

```
instance Monad m => Serial m (TestIt m) where
  series = TestIt <$> (pure <$> series) <~> xxx
```

How to write this `xxx`? I understand that it maybe needs `CoSerial` like function, but 1) I am not sure 2) I don't know how to write it. When I see `CoSerial` documentation, I see that my `CoSerial` will have `Int` and not `D` in its definition:

```
instance (CoSerial m a) => CoSerial m (Int a) where
  coseries rs = ???
```

so I can not get idea of `CoSerial`s and how to use them to make `Serial` for `Int -> m D`.

**Also I want to have dependent serial for `y` field**. I mean if `x` has sample 0 then serial of `y` should get `0` as argument. Is it possible?

Comment: `series = (cons0 $ const $ pure $ B "Xyz") \/ (cons0 $ const $ pure $ A) \/ (cons0 $ \n -> pure $ C $ someLogicOverDepArg n)` for `Serial m (Int -> m D)`. if it is needed variability on `B` then first component should be changed to be series of String.

Comment: Please do not put code in the comments

Answer (score 0):

As example:

```
newtype MyFun m = MyFun (Int -> m D)

instance (Monad m, Monad n) => Serial m (MyFun n) where
  series = MyFun <$> (cons0 $ const $ pure $ A)
                 \/  (cons0 $ const $ pure $ B "XXX")
                 -- it shows how to depend on another field sample
                 \/  (cons0 $ \p -> pure $ C $ show p)
```

And `y` field of `TestIt` should be changed to `MyFun m`.

Then `Serial` instance of `TestIt` becomes trivial.

`B` is using with some constant string, `C` - with parameter, which can be got from sample of `x` field (this shows "dependency" between randomizing samples where one of them is a function):

```
testProperty "diffProcResult" $
   \(t::TestIt Identity) ->
     let (MyFun f) = y t
         yVal = f $ x t
     in ...
```